# Python - Identifying Extraneous Types within a List

Tags: python, list, matrix, element, isinstance

Suppose I have a 2-Dimensional list representing a matrix of numerical values (No, I am not using numPy for this). The allowed types within this list fall under the category of [numbers.Number](https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html). Supposing that I wish to isolate any non-numerical values within this list, such as strings, the only option that I can see is to examine each element individually and check if it is not an instance of numbers.Number:

```
from numbers import Number

def foo(matrix):
   # Check for non-numeric elements in matrix
   for row in matrix:
      for element in row:
         if not isinstance(element, Number):
            raise ValueError('The Input Matrix contains a non-numeric value')
   ...
```

My question is: is there another way to examine the matrix as a whole without looking at each element? Does Python or one of its libraries have a built-in function for identifying extraneous elements within a list (of lists)? Or should I continue with the current example that I provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
print(any(not isinstance(x, Number) for row in matrix for x in row))
```

And in the function:

```
def foo(matrix):
    if any(not isinstance(x, Number) for row in matrix for x in row):
        raise ValueError('The Input Matrix contains a non-numeric value')
```